# Need some clarification on Spring Configuration and Initializer

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have been following this tutorial to build my Spring REST API for a project.

http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-rest-service-example-using-restcontroller/

Now, I have a question. Do i have to create `<class_name>Configuration` and `<class_name>Initializer` class for every rest controller that I am going to make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Configuration and Initializer classes are application context wide. Those are just another way of configuring the Spring application context (the other is using xml configuration files)

Comment: So wouldn't it be better to create one generic class which listens at root level and register it ?

Comment: Exactly. Also, the Configuration classes should have a name describing purpose (or what is being configured there).

Comment: well, if they have application context, why shouldn't i use a more generic name i.e., `<project_name>SpringConfiguration` and `<project_name>SpringInitializer`

Comment: You got it. I usually have one 'main' configuration class (<project>Configuration) which combines couple of other configuration classes with beans for specific configurations (e.g. HibernateConfiguration, TasksConfiguration, ConvertersConfiguration etc.) using @Import annotation.